# How do I estimate the acceptable range?

Tags: logistic, classification, nonlinear-regression, fuzzy

I need to classify candidates as "good" or "bad" where a "good" candidate's age and income, say, must fall within some ranges; I'm trying to discover the boundaries for those ranges.  A candidate must be *both* be the right age *and* have the right income.  I prefer to assume that the boundaries are fuzzy, i.e. sigmoidal or, I suppose, trapezoidal, so I'm estimating not only the location of the boundary but also its sharpness.

Suppose for now that the data I'm fitting on is a large set of candidates where I know their ages and incomes and whether they pass or fail.  (I have a sampling problem, but it's sufficiently complex that I'm splitting it into a [second question](http://Ill.put.a/link_when_/I_post_the.question).)

Although this is a binary classification problem, traditional multivariate logistic modelling won't work because it can't accommodate non-monotonic depedence on the explanatory variables.  That is, afaict, a logistic model can account for a min or a max but not both.

The model I want looks like the product of multiple logistic functions (i.e. an and-gate on multiple univariate logistic models).

So what tools are out there to tackle this kind of problem?  I've seen some papers on "fuzzy membership" models, but I don't really know what I'm looking for.

Comment: I should add that I can do without fuzzy boundaries in my model, though I'm sure the true boundaries in my case are fuzzy.

Comment: Could you use a logistic regression model with squared terms, e.g., with age, age squared, income, and income squared (and possibly interaction terms too if appropriate)?

Comment: that makes a lot of sense to me, @mark999.  I'll give that a shot.  Being relatively unfamiliar with generalized linear models, I find myself wondering whether having such tightly correlated explanatory variables will muck up the underlying framework?

Comment: Having highly correlated explanatory variables isn't ideal, but it's not necessarily a problem. Larger sample sizes can accommodate more highly correlated explanatory variables. I would guess that age and income are not super-highly correlated anyway.

Comment: I do have quite a large volume of data, thankfully.  (The actual problem I'm working on is mass-spec proteomics, btw.  Age and income are just easier to explain than peptide ionizability, and the physical model is basically irrelevant to the statistical problem.)